# Filtering Panda DataFrame parent rows based on a child condition

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a dataframe and a list

```
Person_ID Prod
A         1
B         2 
A         3
C         4
D         5
D         1

exclude_people_who_bought = [1]
```

I would like the following dataframe. In this example, person A and D are excluded because they bought item 1.

```
Person_ID Prod
B         2 
C         4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `isin`

```
out = df.loc[~df.Person_ID.isin(df.loc[df.Prod==1,'Person_ID'])]
  Person_ID  Prod
1         B     2
3         C     4
```